# NSTableView unable automatically reload data

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

Can I do that NSTableView do not respond For automatically reloadData? for example when I click on hide program window, or some sing else? Another words update data in table must implement only when I call realoadData: method?

ps I sink may some method like - unableReload or else, but I can't find it(

Answer (score 0):

I'm find the answer.

for solve this situation Focus Ring of TableView must be '**None**':

```
[tableView setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeNone];
```

Comment: How does the focus ring type relate to when the table view reloads data?